# How do I reposition and resize gameObjects in Unity via scripting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

So I am trying to build a game similar to the Snakes and Ladders game in Unity, but I am finding it hard to deal with when multiple player tokens land on the same square.

I have the following GameObjects in my scene:
[image]

On the click of the Player1 button one of the player tokens (cylindrical gameObjects) advances to the first square (the die is hard coded to roll a 1 everytime for testing purposes) as shown below:
[image]

Now when the Player2 button is clicked the other player token should advance to the first square and it does, however, it overlaps the first player token and it looks like there is only 1 player token in the scene now as shown below:
[image]

I am trying to find a way to resize and reposition both the tokens such that there is enough space between them and they still remain on the same square.

Also, once a player token leaves the square and advances to another square I need to resize the player tokens on both the squares based on whether other player tokens (in case of more than 2 players of course) exist on each square or not

I have tried the following in my method that is called on the click of the button:

```
public void MovePlayerToken(GameObject currentPlayer)
    {
        var startingSquare = currentPlayer.GetComponent<PlayerToken>().StartingSquare;

        var landingSquare = GetLandingSquare(startingSquare);

        var existingPlayerTokensOnLandingSquare = GetExistingPlayerTokens(playerTokens, landingSquare);
        //var existingPlayerTokensOnStartingSquare = GetExistingPlayerTokens(playerTokens, startingSquare);

        if (existingPlayerTokensOnLandingSquare.Count > 0)
        {
            TransformPlayerTokens(existingPlayerTokensOnLandingSquare, landingSquare, SquareType.LandingSquare);

            if (currentPlayer.transform.localScale == new Vector3(1, 1, 1))
            {
                currentPlayer.transform.localScale = new Vector3(currentPlayer.transform.localScale.x / 2,
                    currentPlayer.transform.localScale.y / 2,
                    currentPlayer.transform.localScale.z / 2);
            }

            switch (existingPlayerTokensOnLandingSquare.Count)
            {
                case 1:
                    existingPlayerTokensOnLandingSquare[0].transform.position = new Vector3(landingSquare.transform.localPosition.x + 0.25f, landingSquare.transform.localPosition.y, landingSquare.transform.localPosition.z + 0.25f);
                    currentPlayer.transform.position = new Vector3(landingSquare.transform.localPosition.x + -0.25f, landingSquare.transform.localPosition.y, landingSquare.transform.localPosition.z + -0.25f);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    existingPlayerTokensOnLandingSquare[0].transform.position = new Vector3(landingSquare.transform.localPosition.x + 0.25f, landingSquare.transform.localPosition.y, landingSquare.transform.localPosition.z + 0.25f);
                    existingPlayerTokensOnLandingSquare[1].transform.position = new Vector3(landingSquare.transform.localPosition.x + -0.25f, landingSquare.transform.localPosition.y, landingSquare.transform.localPosition.z + -0.25f);
                    currentPlayer.transform.position = landingSquare.transform.position;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            currentPlayer.transform.position = landingSquare.transform.position;
        }

        currentPlayer.GetComponent<PlayerToken>().StartingSquare = landingSquare;
    }

    private Square GetLandingSquare(Square startingSquare)
    {
        Square landingSquare = startingSquare;

        for (int i = 0; i < _stateManager.DiceTotal; i++)
        {
            if (landingSquare.NextSquares.Length > 1)
                landingSquare = landingSquare.NextSquares[Random.Range(0, landingSquare.NextSquares.Length)];
            else
                landingSquare = landingSquare.NextSquares[0];
        }

        return landingSquare;
    }

    private List<PlayerToken> GetExistingPlayerTokens(PlayerToken[] playerTokens, Square square)
    {
        List<PlayerToken> existingPlayerTokens = new List<PlayerToken>();

        foreach (var playerToken in playerTokens)
        {
            if (playerToken.transform.position == square.transform.position ||
                playerToken.transform.position == new Vector3(square.transform.localPosition.x + 0.25f, square.transform.localPosition.y, square.transform.localPosition.z + 0.25f) ||
                playerToken.transform.position == new Vector3(square.transform.localPosition.x + -0.25f, square.transform.localPosition.y, square.transform.localPosition.z + -0.25f))
            {
                existingPlayerTokens.Add(playerToken);
            }
        }

        return existingPlayerTokens;
    }

    private void TransformPlayerTokens(List<PlayerToken> existingPlayerTokens, Square landingSquare, SquareType squareType)
    {
        foreach (var playerToken in existingPlayerTokens)
        {
            if(playerToken.transform.localScale == new Vector3(1, 1, 1))
            {
                playerToken.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
                    playerToken.transform.localScale.x / 2,
                    playerToken.transform.localScale.y / 2,
                    playerToken.transform.localScale.z / 2
                    );
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with this approach is that the more the player tokens the more hard coding will be needed... I really don't like this approach and I am sure there is a better way to do this using the Physics Engine or something (BTW I am a complete newbie and have never worked with Unity before - this is my first ever project so please expect me to know little to nothing about the Physics Engine)

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this is doable with Physics (especially the required shrink part). But for sure you can create an algorithm that will put them on grids inside a square. 1 players on 1x1 grid, 2-4 players on 2x2 grid, 5-9 on 3x3 and so on. No hard coding this way single algorithm solves all amounts of players.

Comment: @PmDuda Thank you.. I will looking into grids in unity!

Answer (score 0):

You can reposition with GameObject.transform.position = (new position here).

Comment: If you actually read the question, you will realize OP already knows this and this is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

For the resizing, you can do this

```
var players = existingPlayerTokensOnLandingSquare.Count + 1;
currentPlayer.transform.localScale = new Vector3(currentPlayer.transform.localScale.x / players,
                    currentPlayer.transform.localScale.y / players,
                    currentPlayer.transform.localScale.z / players);
```

Don't know about the repositioning, or can't think about that now. Hope someone else can answer that one.

Comment: Positioning could be done with physics. Have colliders and rigidbodies on them, then make walls around the square area or use a script to move them back in if they go out of the area, whichever works I guess. That's too big for me to answer here tho, hope you can figure it out.

Comment: Or you can put them in a grid like the other comment which I only just noticed.

Comment: I did give my squares rigid bodies and on the roll of a die when a player token advances to the square I was able to get the current player token object in the onTriggerEnter method, but have no idea how to identify if other player stones exist on the particular square.